# Should language selectors list in English or in native language?

Tags: user-interface, localization, internationalization

In a UI that lets the user select the language, should the languages in that list be named in:

1. English
2. the language that the UI is currently localised to
3. the native language itself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at what the big guys do. Twitter simply uses the pattern `localized - their language`. This way both will understand. For example, English gets shown as `Engels - English` here, and Simplified Chinese is listed as `Vereenvoudigd Chinees - 简体中文`

Comment: this solution really appeals to me